# Duplicate columns issue when applying migrations files by another team member in django

Tags: python, django, orm, database-migration, django-migrations

I have been facing a huge issue. We are working on a large project with a small team of developers. Now, issue is that when I push the code and in that commit there are some migration files. when other team member pull and merge the code and try to apply the migration files at his side. It gives out duplicate columns issue at his side. Migration files are unapplied but the tables or columns created in those files are in the db at his side. It is very strange that without applying the migrations how can db sense them.
By applying python manage.py showmigrations, the files are unapplied.
Please help me out, things are working at my side but issue at other teammates side and also on beta as well.
I know about the solutions of changing db or deleting migration files but I don't need those.
Looking forward for an immediate help.
Thanks

Comment: Please add exact error message in your question

Comment: Sometimes the error or the code itself speaks much more than what you can convey in your own words. Please [edit] and add the error you get to the question. Also some information about the migrations would be helpful (which ones are applied, which unapplied, perhaps the output of `python manage.py showmigrations` as you have run it, etc.)

Comment: Are you and your team member connected to the same database.

Comment: @RanjanMP
No we have different databases.
But the problem is that it gives duplicate migrations issue at live instance i.e aws